# On Android, can Java call JNI and then the JNI calls back into Java?

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I am just learning android and JNI.  Within Java, from a button click a JNI is being called.  Within the called JNI I call back into Java.
Leaving out the error processing and trying to call a static void method with no parms:

```
void Java_com_example_ndk2_AndroidNDK1SampleActivity_callme(JNIEnv * env, jobject this, int i)
{
   jclass handlerClass = (*env)->FindClass(env, "com/example/ndk2/AndroidNDK1SampleActivity");
   jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, handlerClass, "JavaCallback","()V");
   (*env)->CallStaticVoidMethod(env, mid, NULL);
}
```

The `FindClass` and `GetStaticMethodID` are NOT returning errors.  On the call back to Java, Logcat is indicating from dalvikvm: Invalid indirect reference 0xxxx in decodeIndirectRef.  Any suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the parameter (NULL) you are passing when invoking a method that takes none ("()V").